# Why do I get "Access restricted" when trying to download HDP?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp

Is Horton Data Platform (HDP) still free to use? How can I download its distributive?

I'm trying to download it from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/hdp.html).

[image: picture with error]

Answer (score 0):

The Sandbox is still available to download

https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/hortonworks-sandbox.html

And the DEB/RPM repos should still all work, so you can setup HDP via Ambari

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.5.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html

However, that will eventually be deprecated and no longer supported / upgradable, so you are better off using CDP Data Center

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdpdc/7.0/index.html